# How to convert epoch to datetime in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a column in a bigquery table with epoch values in milliseconds. These include negative epoch values for dates before 1970 also.

How do I convert them into DATETIME format using Standard and Legacy SQL to the format:`1998-10-18 13:45:55`?

This should work even for dates before 1970 .i.e. negative epoch values.

I tried `EXTRACT(DATETIME FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(-2494865480000));`

But it returns me a value with a T included in it: 
`1890-12-10T05:48:40`

Comment: A `DATETIME` format has the `"T" in it.  That is the standard format.  You seem to want a string, but I would recommend leaving the value as a `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting aside that I don't understand your expectation on dates before 1970 you can use `FORMAT_DATETIME` function to format your date result as follow:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME("%F %T", EXTRACT(DATETIME FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(-2494865480000)))
```

The result of this SQL is

> 1890-12-10 05:48:40

Comment: Because there are dates present in the source system before 1970 and it is required. Hence the ask. This was helpful.